# $n$-categories and associahedrons.

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

For $n=2$, turns out that all 2-$categories$ are *strictifiable*, i.e., the notions of weak and strict bicategories coincide. However for $n \geq 3$, the situation becomes wild. In particular, there exists a counterexample sufficiently intuitive (well, as much intuitive as something can be in that context :)) from topology, and a discrepancy between weak and strict 3-groupoids shows up. In general the narrative goes as follows

*"It follows that any non-symmetric braided monoidal category is a weak 3-
category not equivalent to a strict one ... "* (Tom Leinster - Higher Operads and Higher Categories, pg. xxii.)

Now I am going back at the beginning of this post, and particularly to the definition of bicategories. We know that there is a certain axiom showing up, the pentagon axiom, when someone writes down the definition of such a category. For someone with an idea of what a monoidal category is, isn't a big surprise or an ambiguity. Moreover, someone can observe that this pentagon is the same thing as the *"associahedron"* $K_4$. My question is, what happens with the diagrams in an arbitrary $n$-category (choose $n=3$ if you like), and how we generalise this pentagon axiom? Can we make explicit usage of the three dimensional associahedron $K_5$ to describe the generalisation of it in a 3-category for instance? If so, can something be said accordingly for arbitrary $n$ and $K_{n+2}$?

P.S.

I know that writing out diagrams even for 3-cateegories is a difficult task to do, therefore any suggestions for relevant papers or texts along with comments how can someone think of the generalisation of the pentagon axiom might be helpful.

Comment: Rather than the associahedra, which correspond to the $A_\infty = E_1$ operad, I would rather expect the $E_n$ operads (aka little $n$-cubes operads, aka little $n$-disks operads) to appear.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I do expect some sort of operadic interference in the answer. But because am not very familiar with it, I am not sure what sort of relations can someone impose to obtain the operadic-approach instead of the above I mentioned.